# Insert INTO using SELECT * from table with additional columns

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I insert a record to another table with `select * from table` and add additional data?

- `table_a` columns: id, name
- `table_b` columns: id, name, email, phone

My query:

```
INSERT INTO `table_b` 
    SELECT * 
    FROM `table_a` 
    WHERE `id` = '1' + additional data
```

I've found the answer
Query :

```
INSERT INTO `table_b` 
SELECT a.*, 'email@email.com','1234' 
FROM table_a a 
WHERE `id`='2'
```

Thanks

Comment: A table has _columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using.

Comment: what you mean by additional data? values to those extra columns or extra row?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may just add constants to the `SELECT` statement, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO table_b (id, name, email, phone)
SELECT id, name, 'jon.skeet@google.com', '867-5309'
FROM table_a
WHERE id = 1;
```

Note that I explicitly list all columns both from `table_b` and from `table_a`.  While it isn't absolutely required to do this, it makes your code much easier to read, more maintainable, and minimizes the chance for errors later on.

Comment: This is will work.
`INSERT INTO table_b 
SELECT a.*, email='email@email.com', phone='1234' FROM table_a a WHERE id='2'`
Thanks

Comment: "_minimizes the chance for errors later on._" especially when someone alter the table to insert a new column !

Comment: @AxelH Maybe I'm wrong and only adding/removing columns would be a real concern.

Comment: I don't doubt your saying, it would not be the first "what the heck" feature I see ;-) .

Answer (score 1):

You can add this data in your `SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO table_b 
SELECT table_a.id, table_a.name,  email = 'myemail@example.com', phone = '123'
FROM table_a WHERE id='1'
```

of course, the columns have to match.

If only some of the columns (name or simply actual existence) match, you can specify which columns you are inserting (watch for the order!) after the "insert into table_b" statement